# Aws lambda call the sftp server and decrypt the new files and move them

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have an sftp server in which some files come from 3rd parties in `~/raw/in/` folder as  `filename.enc` format. I want to decrypt it using `decrypt filename.enc` command and then that file gets placed in same folder and `.enc` get removed from that file and it becomes `.txt`, after that I want to move it to `~/res/in/` folder.

I want to do this task using AWS lambda server every 5 minutes, to decrypt all the new files which have come to sftp server in `~/raw/in/` folder, and it should also authenticate the lambda server request.

Now I think my lambda server code is ready but I am not getting the other part, should i make a shell script (then how will i call it and how to execute it), or do something else.

LAMBDA CODE

```
def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
    uri = URI("")
    http =  Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
    req.basic_auth "username","password"
    res = http.request(req)
    res.body
end
```

Comment: Where does your "decrypt" command come from?

Comment: decrypt command is present in Linux machine, in a script.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger lambda functions to run on a schedule using cloud watch events. They're very simple to setup, a good guide is here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents.html.

You will want to use a cron expression for how often it runs, for 5 mins it would be `0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *`

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the question